# Why do we have profiles with fraction millimeter dimensions?

Tags: civil-engineering, steel

[image]

We have standard profiles such as this type of tube with outer diameter of 60.3mm, used for example in railing. **Why is it 60.3mm rather than exactly 60mm? In what application does the extra 0.3mm make a significant difference?** I've also seen profiles ending in .7mm. These sound inconvenient to produce compared to full millimiters.

Comment: Lines up close with 2 3/8", granted that's a weird imperial size as well. Could be grandfathered in from older standards.

Comment: Don't know if that's the reason, but machined parts will often have "round" dimensions and buying 60,3 mm raw material will be more economical than taking the next one, say 70 mm, and turning 10 mm off.

Comment: IMHO, its mostly a type of technical debt (or inertia). I think the sizes were first determined for imperial and then while at some point people started to work more with mm, it made more sense in terms of compatibility to round to the closest decimal of a mm. .

Comment: Structurally it doe not make a significant difference, but it can be for the purpose of fitting the parts.

Comment: maybe it is the inside diameter that is important

Comment: I bet it is 2 3/8in, that's 60.325mm. I disagree that it's an unusual diameter, 1/8 inch increments are about the smallest that might matter to an architect.

Comment: I agree (I'm in US). Probably grandfathered in as the size of choice (common use for the application: end caps, unions, & other fittings), then fabricated overseas in Metric. If you replace a part in an existing application, you still want the replacement parts to fit. The size may also have an optical aspect. Letters on signs are sized to be seen from a distance. Is this railing used near roadways (where is this railing used)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circular hollow sections were standardised a long time ago and in inches for historical reasons. This should be obvious if you look at a complete list and convert the units.

The question is better asked the other way around: Why should we change the standard diameter from 60.3mm to 60.0mm, which would an additional cost for the manufactorers, when the 0.3mm difference doesn't make a significant difference anyway?

Comment: And then add all the tools in all the machine shops that would need changing, and also all the fittings, clamps and boxes that would need changing. Starts to be a good reason things continue...

Comment: Google shows that 60.3mm is about 2.374 inches. That sort of repeats my question. Why isn't it 2.4 inches? In what application does the 0.03 inches make much difference?

Comment: Inches are typically/historically divided into fractions, not decimals - 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16 etc. 0.375 is 3/8, which is a common inch fraction.